# SQL inner join with select options as

Tags: abap

I want to do an inner join on the SAP tables BSEG and AUFK.

At my selection screen I have a selection of g/l-accounts (`SELECT-OPTIONS s_hkont FOR hkont.`) and I want tis selection as parameter in my database select.

```
SELECT bseg~hknot, bseg~zuonr FROM bseg INNER JOIN aufk
  ON bseg~hkont IN @s_hkont
  AND aufk~aufnr = bseg~zuonr
  INTO @DATA(output).
ENDSELECT.
```

The keyword `IN` is not supported (`"IN" is invalid here (due to grammar).`).

How can I use `select-options` in a database select with an inner join?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try: only using aufk-aufnr = bseg-zuonr and put the IN part as a where clause.

Comment: NB: a join won't be permitted if `BSEG` is a clustered table as it used to be in SAP ERP versions before S/4HANA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query should look like this.

```
SELECT bseg~hkont, bseg~zuonr FROM bseg INNER JOIN aufk
  ON aufk~aufnr = bseg~zuonr
  WHERE bseg~hkont IN @s_hkont
  INTO @DATA(output).
ENDSELECT.
```